# C# how focus selected item in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I focus the selected item in a DataGridView?
My code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    advancedDataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    advancedDataGridView2.ClearSelection();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in advancedDataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (item.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox1.Text))
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make it so that the selected cell goes into the "edit mode" for the user to type and change it's value?

Give this a try.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    advancedDataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    advancedDataGridView2.ClearSelection();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in advancedDataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (item.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox1.Text))
        {
            advancedDataGridView2.CurrentCell = item.Cells[1];
            advancedDataGridView2.BeginEdit(true);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: By non edit mode do you want to just focus the cell without changing the contents? You can just remove `advancedDataGridView2.BeginEdit(true);`